# regular expression to extract different parts of a url

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a set of different urls with similar pattern and I need to extract the following from each using a regex in javascript. Is it possible to extract different pieces in one command?

1. UUID
2. documenttype
3. document name (demo in this case)
4. images/thumbnail?size=768 or images/thumbnail or images/background
5. thumbnail or background

   /document/b5bacc1e-7b55-4263-97a5-ca7015e367e0/word/demo/con;version=99/images/thumbnail?size=768

   /document/b5bacc1e-7b55-4263-97a5-ca7015e367e0/excel/demo/con;version=99/images/thumbnail?size=100

   /document/b5bacc1e-7b55-4263-97a5-ca7015e367e0/powerpoint/demo/con;version=99/images/thumbnail

   /document/b5bacc1e-7b55-4263-97a5-ca7015e367e0/word/demo/con;version=99/images/background?size=100

   /document/b5bacc1e-7b55-4263-97a5-ca7015e367e0/excel/demo/con;version=99/images/background

My attempt.

```
url.match(/images\/(.*)/);
```

Comment: you need to have different matches....the UUID should be like `[a-z0-9]\{5\}\-[a-z0-9]\{4\}-[a-z0-9]\{4\}-[a-z0-9]\{4\}-[a-z0-9]\{12\}` (but I'm using VIM YMMV).

Comment: is there a way to extract them in one go or do i've to do separately, can we do base on the forward slashes and take whatever is in between?

Comment: You can do an or using |

Comment: And then get each of the matches in an array.

Comment: If you know what order they're in, you can get'm

Comment: In chronological order, just the way the url is, except 4. and 5. but you can switch based on whatever is convenient.

Comment: Don't do this. This problem has already been 100% solved. Use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/url. It's important as a developer to know when to bring in third party modules. This is absolutely that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the structure will always be as the examples you gave, you can use:

```
matches = url.match(/(([a-f0-9]+\-)+[a-f0-9]+)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/.*(images\/([^\?]*).*$)/);
result = {
    "UUID": matches[1],
    "documentType": matches[3],
    "documentName": matches[4],
    "image": matches[5],
    "imageType": matches[6]
}
```

Comment: sorry, documentTypeA-Z shouldn't be taken as literal, it's an enum to be exact, can you please use "excel", "word", "powerpoint", I'm updating my question as well